# Prevent back button from going to Login Page on Android/IOS in a Gluon App

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I have a Gluon Mobile (Glisten Afterburner) App and would like to prevent the user from going to the Login Screen of the App on pressing the back button in Android.

There are ways to do this for a particular activity in Android native code. How do I implement it in Gluon.

Comment: means you want to restrict the user to go on login screen when user is inside the app and he is on the other screen?

Comment: Yes, I want to restrict the user from going to the login screen when the user is inside the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @Bek's answer will work on a pure Android approach, using Gluon Views and the Glisten-Afterburner framework, there is an equivalent way:

When you create your project with that template, there are two views, defined with some flags, as you can see in `AppViewManager`:

```
public static final AppView PRIMARY_VIEW = view("Primary", PrimaryPresenter.class, MaterialDesignIcon.HOME, 
    SHOW_IN_DRAWER, HOME_VIEW, SKIP_VIEW_STACK);
public static final AppView SECONDARY_VIEW = view("Secondary", SecondaryPresenter.class, MaterialDesignIcon.DASHBOARD, 
    SHOW_IN_DRAWER);
```

The flags applied to each view are self explanatory, but if you recall, there is a `SKIP_VIEW_STACK` flag, applied to the Primary view (which is the Home View): this means the Primary view is not added to the stack, and when you hit back on it, you won't go to other previous view you were before, you will just finish the application.

You can apply this flag to the secondary view as well, and this will mean that once you move from the Primary View to the Secondary View, you won't be able to go back to the primary view again.

So I've renamed the views, the first one will be the Login View, and when you move to the Primary View you won't be able to go back to it via back button:

```
public static final AppView LOGIN_VIEW = view("Login", LoginPresenter.class, MaterialDesignIcon.HOME, 
    SHOW_IN_DRAWER, HOME_VIEW, SKIP_VIEW_STACK);
public static final AppView PRIMARY_VIEW = view("Primary", PrimaryPresenter.class, MaterialDesignIcon.DASHBOARD, 
    SHOW_IN_DRAWER, SKIP_VIEW_STACK);
```

At a later state, you can always go to the login view programmatically, if you need to.

Comment: Thanks Jose! the SKIP_VIEW_STACK in the  second screen after login worked

Comment: Hi @José Pereda, encountered the problem that the app is relaunching with the login screen on resuming the application (i.e clicked back button on the second screen it minimizes the app and on clicking the App icon the app launches with login screen ) I want to resume the app with the second screen

Comment: When you say the back button "minimizes the app", actually what happens is that the app is closed. When you click the icon again, a new instance is opened, obviously showing the login screen. Note that by skipping the first (login) view from the stack, the next view becomes the home view, and clicking back will finish the app.

Answer (score 0):

After calling startActivity(intent) on LoginActivity call finish(). It will remove LoginActivity from stack.

Comment: Same as above, Thanks for the responses but I'm trying to implement this on a Gluon app and not a Native Android App